# 大きなサイズの画像をiOSやAndroidのブラウザで表示するためのサービスや技術

Tags: ios, android, 画像

現在ウェブサイトを作成しており、その中で28800x16200pixelの画像を公開したいと考えております。

Gyazo等のアップローダーで表示しようとした場合、PCでは表示できるのですが、
iOSのSafariで表示しようとした場合にクラッシュしてしまいます。

直接表示するとiPhoneのメモリの制約上しょうがないかと思いますが、
ブラウザの中で拡大ができるビューワーがあれば
iPhone上では画面の解像度を上限とした表示になるので
うまく表示できるのではないかと考えています。

どなたかそのようなサービスや技術をご存じないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

元画像をいくつかに分割し、それらをタイルとして敷き詰めて表示するのが一般的だと思います。ユーザーの操作に合わせて表示箇所を動的に読み込むなどの処理を JavaScript で実装することになります。

「タイルマップ」などの語で検索すると、ライブラリや解説が有ると思います。ただ、分野としてはゲームや地図向けのものが多そうです。

高解像の画像用のものに絞って探す場合は、「high resolution」や「large image」などの語を一緒に検索するとよいかも知れません。例えば、[OpenSeadragon](https://openseadragon.github.io/) などが見つかりました。